# Appropriate name for container of position, size, angle

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

I have something like an artboard which users can place picture objects.

Each picture object can be moved around, resized and changed its rotation angle.

I have a class stores picture's position, size and angle.
I wonder what could be appropriate name for that class.

I cannot think of any word summarizes "Position", "Size" and "Angle".

I'm am also not a native English speaker so if anyone could help finding appropriate name for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Aspect" might be good, or "Appearance", or "Presentation"...

Comment: @Bigair       ok, great