# Refactoring Business Rule, Function Naming, Width, Height, Position X & Y

Tags: refactoring, naming-conventions, naming, business-logic

I am refactoring some business rule functions to provide a more generic version of the function.

The functions I am refactoring are:

```
DetermineWindowWidth
DetermineWindowHeight
DetermineWindowPositionX
DetermineWindowPositionY
```

All of them do string parsing, as it is a string parsing business rules engine.

My question is what would be a good name for the newly refactored function?
Obviously I want to shy away from a function name like:

```
DetermineWindowWidthHeightPositionXPositionY
```

I mean that would work, but it seems unnecessarily long when it could be something like:
`DetermineWindowMoniker` or something to that effect.

**Function objective:** Parse an input string like 1280x1024 or 200,100 and return either the first or second number. The use case is for data-driving test automation of a web browser window, but this should be irrelevant to the answer.

**Question objective:** I have the code to do this, so my question is not about code, but just the function name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this question-answer provides a good starting point to answer this question:
[Appropriate name for container of position, size, angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564820/appropriate-name-for-container-of-position-size-angle)

A search on [www.thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com) for "Property" gives some interesting possible answers that provide enough meaningful context to the usage:

```
Aspect
Character
Characteristic
Trait
Virtue
Property
Quality
Attribute
Differentia
Frame
Constituent
```

I think `ConstituentProperty` is probably the most apt.

Answer (score 1):

There are too little details, you should have specified at least the parameters and returns of the functions.

- Have I understood correctly that you use strings of the format *N*x*N* for sizes and *N*,*N* for positions?
- And that this generic function will have to parse both (and nothing else), and will return either the first or second part depending on a parameter of the function?
- And that you'll then keep the various `DetermineWindow*` functions but make them all call this generic function?

#### If so:

Without knowing what parameters the generic function has it's even harder to help, but it's most likely impossible to give it a simple name.
Not all batches of code can be described by a simple name.

You'll most likely need to use a different construction if you want to have clear names. Here's an idea, in pseudo code:

```
ParseSize(string, outWidth, outHeight) {
    ParsePair(string, "x", outWidht, outHeight)
}

ParsePosition(string, outX, outY) {
    ParsePair(string, ",", outX, outY)
}

ParsePair(string, separator, outFirstItem, outSecondItem) {
    ...
}
```

And the various `DetermineWindow` would call `ParseSize` or `ParsePosition`.
You could also use just `ParsePair`, directly, but I thinks it's cleaner to have the two other functions in the middle.

---

#### Objects

Note that you'd probably get cleaner code by using objects rather than strings (a `Size` and a `Position` one, and probably a `Pair` one too).
The `ParsePair` code (adapted appropriately) would be included in a constructor or factory method that gives you a Pair out of a string.

### ---

Of course you can give other names to the various functions, objects and parameters, here I used the first that came to my mind.

Comment: I like the ParsePair answer, that is an interesting take.